# laravel - Resize images and save to Amazon S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, intervention

When the user upload his profile pic i want to create 3 versions of this image with different sizes, then upload everything to amazon s3.

I use image intervention package for resizing images, this my code so far.

```
public function store(Request $request){

    if($request->has('avatar')){

        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');

        $filename = md5(time()).'_'.$avatar->getClientOriginalName();

        $normal = Image::make($avatar)->resize(160, 160);

        $medium = Image::make($avatar)->resize(80, 80);

        $small = Image::make($avatar)->resize(40, 40);

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/users/'.Auth::user()->uuid.'/avatars/normal/'.$filename, fopen($normal, 'r+'), 'public');

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/users/'.Auth::user()->uuid.'/avatars/medium/'.$filename, fopen($medium, 'r+'), 'public');

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/users/'.Auth::user()->uuid.'/avatars/small/'.$filename, fopen($small, 'r+'), 'public');

        $user = User::findorFail(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

When i try to submit the file i got this error.

```
fopen(): Filename cannot be empty
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does `Image::make($avatar)->resize(160, 160)` return?

Comment: It returns an instance of Image class but its shows null in the image property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE** i made it work like this, if someone has the same issue i hope he will find this code helpful.

```
public function store(Request $request){

    if($request->has('avatar')){

        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $extension = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $filename = md5(time()).'_'.$avatar->getClientOriginalName();

        $normal = Image::make($avatar)->resize(160, 160)->encode($extension);
        $medium = Image::make($avatar)->resize(80, 80)->encode($extension);
        $small = Image::make($avatar)->resize(40, 40)->encode($extension);

        //$path = '/users/'.Auth::user()->uuid.'/avatar/normal/'.$filename;

        //dd($normal);

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/users/'.Auth::user()->uuid.'/avatar/normal/'.$filename, (string)$normal, 'public');

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/users/'.Auth::user()->uuid.'/avatar/medium/'.$filename, (string)$medium, 'public');

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/users/'.Auth::user()->uuid.'/avatar/small/'.$filename, (string)$small, 'public');

        $user = User::findorFail(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a helper controller you can try it.
https://github.com/RashiqulRony/Help_Content/blob/master/MediaController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Image;

class MediaController
{
    public $basePath = '';
    public $originalPath = '';
    public $file = '';
    public $name = '';
    public $thumbPath = '';
    public $thumb = false;
    public $storageFolder = 'storage/';
    public $imageResize = [];
    public $thumbResize = [300, 300];

    //Common File Upload Function...
    private function upload()
    {
        $file = $this->file;
        if ($this->name) {
            $fileName = Str::slug($this->name, '-').'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        } else {
            $newName = str_replace('.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(), '', $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $fileName = time().'-'.Str::slug($newName, '-').'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        }
        $data['name'] = $fileName;
        $data['originalName'] = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $data['size'] = $file->getSize();
        $data['mime_type'] = $file->getMimeType();
        $data['ext'] = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $data['url'] = url($this->storageFolder.$this->originalPath.$data['name']);

        //If real image need to resize...
        if (!empty($this->imageResize)) {
            $file = Image::make($file)->resize($this->imageResize[0], $this->imageResize[1]);
            Storage::put($this->originalPath.'/'.$fileName, (string) $file->encode());
        } else {
            Storage::putFileAs($this->originalPath, $file, $data['name']);
        }

        if ($this->thumb) {
            Image::make($this->storageFolder.$this->originalPath.$data['name'])
                ->resize($this->thumbResize[0], $this->thumbResize[1])
                ->save($this->storageFolder.$this->thumbPath.'/'.$data['name']);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    //Upload Image ("$definePath" and "$definePath/thumb") folder....
    public function imageUpload($requestFile, $path, $thumb = false, $name = null, $imageResize = [], $thumbResize = [300, 300])
    {
        //Path Create...
        $realPath = $this->basePath.$path.'/';
        if (!Storage::exists($realPath)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($realPath);
        }

        if (!Storage::exists($realPath.'thumb') && $thumb) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($realPath.'thumb');
        }

        $this->file = $requestFile;
        $this->originalPath = $realPath;
        $this->thumbPath = $realPath.'thumb';
        $this->thumb = $thumb;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->imageResize = $imageResize;
        $this->thumbResize = $thumbResize;
        return $this->upload();
    }

    //Upload Video in "$definePath" folder....
    public function videoUpload($requestFile, $path, $name = null)
    {
        //Path Create...
        $realPath = $this->basePath.$path.'/';
        if (!Storage::exists($realPath)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($realPath);
        }

        $this->file = $requestFile;
        $this->originalPath = $realPath;
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this->upload();
    }

    //Upload AnyFile in "$definePath" folder....
    public function anyUpload($requestFile, $path, $name = null)
    {
        //Path Create...
        $realPath = $this->basePath.$path.'/';
        if (!Storage::exists($realPath)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($realPath);
        }

        $this->file = $requestFile;
        $this->originalPath = $realPath;
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this->upload();
    }


    //Upload Content in "$definePath" folder....
    public function contentUpload($content, $path, $name)
    {
        //Path Create...
        $realPath = $this->basePath.$path.'/';
        if (!Storage::exists($realPath)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($realPath);
        }

        Storage::put($name, $content);

        $data['name'] = $name;
        $data['url'] = $path.'/'.$name;
        return $data;
    }

    //Only thumb image create in "$definePath/thumb" folder....
    public function thumb($path, $file, $thumbPath = false, $thumbWidth = 300, $thumbHeight = 300)
    {
        $realPath = $this->basePath.$path;
        if (!$thumbPath) {
            $thumbPath = $this->basePath.$path.'/thumb';
        }

        if (!Storage::exists($thumbPath)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($thumbPath);
        }

        $img = Image::make($this->storageFolder.$realPath.'/'.$file)
            ->resize($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight)
            ->save($this->storageFolder.$thumbPath.'/'.$file);

        if (isset($img->filename)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Delete file "$definePath" folder....
    public function delete($path, $file, $thumb = false)
    {
        $path = $this->basePath.$path.'/';
        if (Storage::exists($path.'/'.$file)) {
            Storage::delete($path.'/'.$file);

            if ($thumb) {
                Storage::delete($path.'/thumb/'.$file);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Intervention, be sure to give the path of the file in your filesystem.
What I can see there is that you are giving a string (name of the file, not the path).
So Intervention can create an image because of that.

So you can first save the file in your local filesystem and then give that full path when calling:

```
$normal = Image::make($full_path)->resize(160, 160);
```